# Java custom constraints validator fails in unit tests with "No target Validator set" error

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, javax.validation

I have springboot application which wires up validatorFactoryBean like this

```
private LocalValidatorFactoryBean validatorFactoryBean;

@Autowired
public void setValidatorFactoryBean(LocalValidatorFactoryBean validatorFactoryBean) {
    this.validatorFactoryBean = validatorFactoryBean;
}
```

I have custom validators defined on class Car and I run the validations like this.

```
 Set<ConstraintViolation<Car>> constraintViolations = validatorFactoryBean.validate(myCar);
```

All of this works fine. But when I try to test this thru unit tests, on the line

```
validatorFactoryBean.validate(myCar)
```

I get an error "No target Validator set".

This is how I am setting up validatorFactoryBean in the testng unit test

```
@InjectMocks
LocalValidatorFactoryBean validatorFactoryBean;
```

I pass this in to the class I am testing by calling setValidatorFactoryBean setter.

While debugging I realized this validatorFactoryBean is not aware of all the ConstraintValidator implementations in the main code.

How do I make validatorFactoryBean aware of all the ConstraintValidator implementations?

This is how the car constraint validator looks like

```
public class CarConstraintImpl implements ConstraintValidator<CarConstraint, req> {

    @Inject
    FuelDependency fuelDependency;

    public CarConstraintImpl() {
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Request req, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintContext) {
        try {
            fuelDependency.check(req);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //some code
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: How are you starting up your tests. You mention unit test, but you expect spring beans to be there. Is it a @SpringBootTest, or extended with spring extension, or only unit tests? My first impression is that the bean is not created when you run your tests. For more help I'd need to see how you created the validator, how your Car class is using it, and how you setup the tests. Also did you check if the validator is overridden the 'supports' method to support class 'Car'?

Comment: Not a SpringBootTest

Comment: @developer747 Can you provide the test class or [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: If it is not a SpringBootTest, how are you then running the test? It needs a bean for the validation. If you use SpringExtension, you need some sort of spring context configuration. If you use plain unit test, the bean will never be there, and you need to create a new Validator object & autowiring will never work.

Answer (score 2):

`@InjectMocks` is just a mockito stuff and never understand spring. It just like you create a `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` manually without any spring integration to it.

To configure `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` properly , you can do it by using `@SpringBootTest` with the  `@ImportAutoConfiguration` to auto-configure just the bean validation stuff.

```
@SpringBootTest
public class ValidationTest{


    @Configuration
    @ImportAutoConfiguration(ValidationAutoConfiguration.class)                
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "my.app.root.package" })
    public static class Config {

    }

    @Autowired
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean validatorFactoryBean;
    

    @Test
    void test(){
    
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest that you use a `@SpringBootTest`, as described in Ken's answer. But if for some reason you don't want to, a `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` object initialized using the below code should work for tests as long as all of the custom constraint validators have a default, no-args constructor:

```java
LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
validator.afterPropertiesSet();
```

Answer (score 1):

**(Option 1)** If the `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` is created by a Spring container, then some additional logic is executed during the [`afterPropertiesSet()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/LocalValidatorFactoryBean.html#afterPropertiesSet()) phase.

You could replicate this by calling this method by yourself. For example:

```java
@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    validator.afterPropertiesSet();
}
```

**(Option 2)** However, this is kind of a hack, because the default `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` created by Spring Boot contains [extra customizers and a message interpolator](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/f37d6c9294788720fbea27c925f55d5ce52b4fcb/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/ValidationAutoConfiguration.java#L55-L66). If you don't care about this, it might be cleaner to work with the underlying JSR-380 bean validator in stead. For example:

```java
@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    validator = factory.getValidator();
}
```

Be aware that `validator` will be a different type, but it also contains a `validate()` method with the same signature.

**(Option 3)** If you do care about the additional setup Spring provides, then you could write a Spring integration test. I don't recommend using `@SpringBootTest` as you would bloat your tests.

All you really need is to include the `SpringExtension` and the necessary autoconfiguration:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ImportAutoConfiguration(ValidationAutoConfiguration.class)
public class MyValidationTest {
    @Autowired
    private LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator;
}
```